# 'SmartyException' with message 'Missing template name' in Smarty

Tags: php, compiler-errors, smarty

I got the error saying "SmartyException' with message 'Missing template name...".
I'd love to show the different page using display() in Smarty. I get the value from the url and deferenciate the page.
I tried concatenate the single quote, but it doesn't really work. 
Any helps appreciate.
index.html , confirm.html , finish.html exist in contact folder in a template directory.

```
switch($_GET['param']) {
    case 1: confirmation();
    break;

    case 2: send_email();
    break;

    case 3: finish();
    break;
}


function confirmation(){
    echo 'index page';

//$smarty->assign('css', "contact");
//$smarty->display('contact/index.html');
    $url = '\'contact/index.html\'';
}

function send_email(){
    echo 'confirmation page';

//$smarty->assign('css', "contact");
//$smarty->display('contact/confirm.html');
    $url = '\'contact/confirm.html\'';
}

function finish(){
    echo 'finish page';

//$smarty->assign('css', "contact");
//$smarty->display('contact/finish.html');
    $url = '\'contact/finish.html\'';
}



//
$smarty->assign('css', "contact");
//$smarty->display('contact/index.html');
$smarty->display($url);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you make `$url` a local variable in each function. You should create global variable and return `$url` in each function as in the following code:

```
$url = '';
switch($_GET['param']) {
    case 1: 
       $url = confirmation();
       break;

    case 2: 
       $url = send_email();
       break;

    case 3: 
       $url = finish();
       break;
}


function confirmation(){
    echo 'index page';

//$smarty->assign('css', "contact");
//$smarty->display('contact/index.html');
    $url = 'contact/index.html';
    return $url;
}

function send_email(){
    echo 'confirmation page';

//$smarty->assign('css', "contact");
//$smarty->display('contact/confirm.html');
    $url = 'contact/confirm.html';
    return $url;
}

function finish(){
    echo 'finish page';

//$smarty->assign('css', "contact");
//$smarty->display('contact/finish.html');
    $url = 'contact/finish.html';
    return $url;
}



//
$smarty->assign('css', "contact");
//$smarty->display('contact/index.html');
$smarty->display($url);
```

By the way I removed also  single quotes from `$url` in each function because they don't seem to be necessary at all.