# SmartyException 0():Missing '$template' parameter with Prestashop

Tags: php, prestashop

I am using PrestaShop for my online store 
https://www.fyndpris.co.uk/ 
The desktop version is working perfectly but i have a problem with AMP NOT in the homepage but when i am trying to access some products like this link : 
https://www.fyndpris.co.uk/mobile/product/8282714-fyndpris-children-s-loft-bed-frame-with-slide-ladder-pinewood-97x208-cm

```
 (1/1) SmartyException
0():Missing '$template' parameter

in smarty_internal_templatebase.php line 177
at Smarty_Internal_TemplateBase->_execute(null, null, 'layouts/layout-full-width.tpl', null, 0)
in smarty_internal_templatebase.php line 116
at Smarty_Internal_TemplateBase->fetch(null, null, 'layouts/layout-full-width.tpl', null, false, true, false)
in SmartyDev.php line 40
at SmartyDev->fetch(null, null, 'layouts/layout-full-width.tpl')
in FrontController.php line 683
at FrontControllerCore->smartyOutputContent(null)
in FrontController.php line 667
at FrontControllerCore->display()
in Controller.php line 312
at ControllerCore->run()
in Dispatcher.php line 515
at DispatcherCore->dispatch()
in index.php line 28
```

Note that i have reviewed these two question about the same Error : 
1- [question1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26045425/uncaught-exception-smartyexception-with-message-missing-template-name-in-smar)

but i can'y find out a solution for my problem

[4]: ['SmartyException' with message 'Missing template name' in Smarty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24987975/smartyexception-with-message-missing-template-name-in-smarty) . 
I will disable the Amp for now to avoid make the user face the Error before i find the solution 
Knowing that i have posted many question at PrestaShop community but unfortunately there was no answer 
I hope i described my problem correctly

Comment: What's your prestashop version ?

Comment: it is last one 1.7.6.1

Comment: It will be tricky to help you, as your question is on a module. Is it free ? If not, you will have to ask directly the module support. Else, share its link

Comment: How is my problem related to module ? 
I am just using amp provided with my Theme i have no module

Comment: Then is your theme free ? Generally, a theme can come with a list of modules included

Comment: what I'm saying that's not a prestashop **default** behaviour (I think according to the product page url), so if you want help, you have to describe what you added to your prestashop

Comment: okay , thank you for your help 
I will try to find out what did i add and i will come back

Comment: do you remember how you have fixed this error ? thank you

Comment: This is a well known Prestashop bug. [Here](https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/issues/20921) you will find it discussed on their Github. There still isn't a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same error, using a frontcontroller for a cron rutine... so I wrote again the Controller keeping the structure as the documentation

"Minimum controller example" and "Using a front controller as a cron task" in
https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/modules/concepts/controllers/front-controllers/

so, check structure maybe this could solve the problem

Answer (score -5):

Refresh the smarty cache in Presta performance settings