# Prestashop PHP Smarty Errors

Tags: prestashop, smarty

My error_log file keeps getting filled with this error and i don't know what is causing it. Any idea how i can find what is causing the error ?

```
[14-Aug-2020 13:20:32 Europe/Bucharest] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught  --> Smarty: 0():Missing '$template' parameter <-- 
  thrown in /home/website/public_html/vendor/smarty/smarty/libs/sysplugins/smarty_internal_templatebase.php on line 177
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means somewhere in the code there is a variable called `{$template}` which is not defined. It could be theme templates or modules
I would use IDE to look for this variable. If this doesnt work just go for debuging technique, start where smarty starts rendering and go till place where it crashes :)

It looks like it is a dublicate for this question, maybe will help

> [SmartyException 0():Missing '$template' parameter with Prestashop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58686542/smartyexception-0missing-template-parameter-with-prestashop)

Answer (score 0):

This also might be due to messed up module structure, its ModuleFrontControllers etc.

You can try to edit this file:

`thrown in /home/website/public_html/vendor/smarty/smarty/libs/sysplugins/smarty_internal_templatebase.php on line 177`

and check if you can log more informations about an error, file path etc.